# Print python output to word doc or PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, printing, ms-word

Does anyone have a simple way to print python output to a word doc? I want to capture the print statements and plot in a PDF (without showing any code). right now i am just copy and pasting, wondering if there is an easier way.

- a-o are just random ints

```py
group_a = (a,b,c,d,e)
group_b = (f,g,h,i,j)
group_c = (k,l,m,n,o)

width = 0.2

x = np.arange(5)

plt.bar(x-0.2, group_a, width, color = 'cyan')
plt.bar(x, group_b, width, color = 'orange')
plt.bar(x+0.2, group_c, width, color = 'green')

plt.xticks(x, ['1','2','3','4','5'])
plt.xlabel("quarter")

plt.ylabel('%')

plt.legend(['Group A','Group B','Group C'])


print(f'Group A: {a},{b},{c},{d},{e}')
print(f'Group B: {f},{g},{h},{i},{j}')
print(f'Group C: {k},{l},{m},{n},{o}')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `matplotlib.pyplot`, you should be able to  go with `plt.savefig('line_plot.pdf')`

Comment: what if i have multiple figures? would they all be separate PDFS?

Comment: No, they'll all be in the same pdf file - you can try the code to see if the output is what you want. If you would prefer separate PDFs then you can make multiple plots and save them separately. Please accept this answer if it resolves your question.